# Button BackColor Won't Change in Backgroundworker Completed Method

Tags: c#-4.0, backgroundworker, backcolor

1) I click the start connect button in my client program. I successfully set the start button backcolor to red.

2) When the TCP connection is completed, a registration message is sent and it successfully changes the button backcolor to yellow.

3) The server sends a registration ACK back to the client and that is processed in a backgroundworker (BGW). BGW sets a boolean variable SetConnectButton so that it is known registration was successful, then completes.

4) The RunWorkerCompleted function is ran. The debug window displays "Lime" as it should, but the button color does not change. Here is the RunWorkerCompleted code.

```
static private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
        if (SetConnectButton)
            {
            Debug.WriteLine("Lime");
            SetConnectButton = false;
            UIMain.btnServerConnect.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;
            }
        }//close WorkerCompleted
```

As I understand it, the RunWorkerCompleted runs in the UI thread so this should work as is. Using Invoke made no difference, though I may not have done it right.

Any clues?

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point in that event handler?  Are you sure `SetConnectButton` is true?

Comment: Yes, SetConnectButton is true, since the word "Lime" appears in the Debug output.

BTW, UIMain is set to "this" in the constructor for the main form, where the button in question resides.

Comment: Where is it written on msdn that runworkercompleted runs in the UI thread?

Comment: I found it in a couple places.

1) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Create an event handler for the RunWorkerCompleted event.
The RunWorkerCompleted event is raised when the background worker has completed. Depending on whether the background operation completed successfully, encountered an error, or was canceled, update the user interface accordingly.

Comment: 2) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted(v=vs.100).aspx

#1 & #2 imply this, as the examples for RunWorkerCompleted show changes to the UI being made.

Comment: Also, a comment at the very bottom of #1 says:

The answer is that the thread that fires the event DoWork is not the same thread that fires either the ProgressChanged or RunWorkerCompleted. The latter two are fired on the UI thread (or the thread the RunWorkerAsync method was called from), whereas the DoWork is called on a threadpool thread.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by using Context.Post method when calling the function that writes the UI.